# Excel - Help Needed with Formulas

Tags: excel-formula

I'm looking to try do the following;

I want to have say 3 columns.

Transaction | Category | Amount

so I want to be able to enter a certain Name in Transaction say for argument sake "Tesco" then have a returned result in Category Column say "Groceries" and I can enter a specific amount then myself in Amount Colum.

Thing is I will need to have unlimited or quite a lot of different Transactions and have them all in pre determined Categories so that each time when I type in a Transaction it will automatically display the category for me.

All help much appreciated.
I know a simple If Statement wont suffice I can get it to work no problem using a Simple IF Statement but as each Transaction is different I don't know how to program further.

Thanks.
Colin

Comment: Can 1 transaction have multiple categories?

Comment: Your problem looks more complex to be solved with formulas.Do you have an example and any idea how you are trying to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Use a lookup table. Let's say it's on a sheet called "Categories" and it looks like this:

```
  |  A    |  B
1 | Name  | Category
2 | Tesco | Groceries
3 | Shell | Fuel
```

Then, in the table you describe, use `=VLOOKUP(A2, Categories!$A$2:$B$3, 2, FALSE)` in your "Category" field, assuming it's in B2.

Answer (score 1):

I do this a fair bit using Data Validation and tables.

In this case I would have two tables containing my pick lists on a lookup sheet.

Transaction Table :  [Name] = "loTrans" - with just the list of transactions **sorted**

Category Table : [Name] = "loCategory" - two columns in table, **sorted by Both columns - Trans and Category**

- Header1 : Transactions
- Header2 : Category

[image: Pick List table Example]

The Details Table:

- the transaction field will have a simple data validation, using a
  named range "trans", that selects from the table loTrans.
- the transaction field will also use data validation, using a named
  range, but the source of the named range ("selCat" will be a little more
  complex.  It will be something like:

  =OFFSET(loCategory[Trans],MATCH(Enter_Details!A3,loCategory[Trans],0)-1,1,COUNTIF(loCategory[Trans],Enter_Details!A3),1)
- As you enter details, and select different Transactions, the data validation will be limited to the Categorys of your selected transactions

[image]

[An example file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yirgy1er2gm02hx/Data%20Validation.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: That looks fab but would you be able to send me a sample so I could use and amend to what I need please?

Comment: Hi - out at the moment.  Will do it tomorrow morning.

Comment: Edited answer with link to example file